# Access mule variables inside java classes without passing variable as arguments in Mule 4.3

Tags: java, variables, mule-component, mulesoft, mule4

Can we access mule variables in the mule flow inside java classes without passing each variable as arguments to method in Mule 4.3?

Answer (score 0):

You should not attempt to do that. That is explicitly considered a bad practice in the documentation. See https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/general-coding-rules#never-access-flow-variables